# Pandas, long processing time of groupby and comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, but through stackoverflow, have gotten things to work. This currently works but takes about 30 minutes (pretty large dataset).  Was wondering if there was a way to speed this up?  Essentially trying to map out the various different combinations of the 'Status' column with the 'Current_Status' column.  Thanks!

```
df_new = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(   
new_col1=(x['foo'] != np.nan).sum(),    
new_col2=(x['bar'] == 'P').sum(),
new_col3=(x['bar'] == 'C').sum(),
new_col3=((x['Status']=='Approved, not yet paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, paid')).sum(),
new_col4=((x['Status']=='Approved, not yet paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, not yet paid')).sum(),
new_col5=((x['Status']=='Approved, paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, paid')).sum()
)))
```

Example of df structure:

```
In[15]: df.head(6)
Out[15]:
   id   foo  bar  Status                   Current_Status
0  1    23   'C'  'Approved, paid'         'Approved, paid'
1  1    63   'P'  'Approved, not yet paid' 'Approved, paid'
2  1    84   'P'  'Approved, paid'         'Approved, paid'
3  1    125  'P'  'Approved, not yet paid' 'Approved, not yet paid'
4  1    216  'P'  'Approved, not yet paid' 'Approved, paid'
5  1    12   'C'  'Approved, paid'         'Approved, paid'
```

Comment: Can you add sample data? `5-6 rows`

Comment: Just did so.  I'm sure the syntax of the "Out[15]" is off.  Please disregard that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df_new1 = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(
 new_col1=(x['foo'].notnull()).sum(),
 new_col2=np.in1d(x['bar'],'P').sum(),
 new_col3=np.in1d(x['bar'],'C').sum(),
 new_col4=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, not yet paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, paid'])).sum(),
 new_col5=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, not yet paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, not yet paid'])).sum(),
 new_col6=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, paid'])).sum()
)))
```

Another faster solution convert values to values `0` and `1` by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html), then create inverted columns by [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df['new_col1'] = df['foo'].notnull().astype(int)
df['new_col2'] = df['bar'].factorize()[0]
df['new_col3'] = (df['new_col2'] - 1).abs()
df['Status'] =  df['Status'].factorize()[0]
df['invertStatus'] = (df['Status'] - 1).abs()
df['Current_Status'] = df['Current_Status'].factorize()[0]
df['invertCurrent_Status'] = (df['Current_Status'] - 1).abs()

df['new_col4'] = df['Status'] & df['invertCurrent_Status']
df['new_col5'] = df['Status'] & df['Current_Status']
df['new_col6'] = df['invertStatus'] & df['invertCurrent_Status']

print df.groupby('id').sum()
                        [['new_col1','new_col2','new_col3','new_col4','new_col5','new_col6']]
```

Or you can create boolean `Series` - the fastest solution:

```
df['new_col1'] = df['foo'].notnull()
df['new_col2'] = np.in1d(df['bar'], 'P')
df['new_col3'] = ~df['new_col2']
Status =  np.in1d(df['Status'],'Approved, not yet paid')
invertStatus = ~Status
Current_Status = np.in1d(df['Current_Status'],'Approved, not yet paid')
invertCurrent_Status = ~Current_Status

df['new_col4'] = Status & invertCurrent_Status
df['new_col5'] = Status & Current_Status
df['new_col6'] = invertStatus & invertCurrent_Status
#print df

print df.groupby('id').sum()
        [['new_col1','new_col2','new_col3','new_col4','new_col5','new_col6']].astype(int)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [25]: len(df)
Out[25]: 110000

In [26]: %timeit a(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.7 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit b(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.3 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit c(df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 46 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit d(df3)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

**Code**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)    
#print df
df1,df2,df3 = df.copy(), df.copy(), df.copy()


def a(df):
    df['new_col1'] = df['foo'].notnull()
    df['new_col2'] = np.in1d(df['bar'], 'P')
    df['new_col3'] = ~df['new_col2']
    Status =  np.in1d(df['Status'],'Approved, not yet paid')
    invertStatus = ~Status
    Current_Status = np.in1d(df['Current_Status'],'Approved, not yet paid')
    invertCurrent_Status = ~Current_Status
    df['new_col4'] = Status & invertCurrent_Status
    df['new_col5'] = Status & Current_Status
    df['new_col6'] = invertStatus & invertCurrent_Status
    #print df
    return df.groupby('id').sum()[['new_col1','new_col2','new_col3','new_col4','new_col5','new_col6']].astype(int)

def b(df):
    df['new_col1'] = df['foo'].notnull().astype(int)
    df['new_col2'] = df['bar'].factorize()[0]
    df['new_col3'] = (df['new_col2'] - 1).abs()
    df['Status'] =  df['Status'].factorize()[0]
    df['invertStatus'] = (df['Status'] - 1).abs()
    df['Current_Status'] = df['Current_Status'].factorize()[0]
    df['invertCurrent_Status'] = (df['Current_Status'] - 1).abs()

    df['new_col4'] = df['Status'] & df['invertCurrent_Status']
    df['new_col5'] = df['Status'] & df['Current_Status']
    df['new_col6'] = df['invertStatus'] & df['invertCurrent_Status']

    return df.groupby('id').sum()[['new_col1','new_col2','new_col3','new_col4','new_col5','new_col6']]
```

```
def c(df):
    return df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(new_col1=(x['foo'].notnull()).sum(),new_col2=np.in1d(x['bar'],'P').sum(),new_col3=np.in1d(x['bar'],'C').sum(),new_col4=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, not yet paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, paid'])).sum(),new_col5=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, not yet paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, not yet paid'])).sum(),new_col6=(np.in1d(x['Status'],['Approved, paid']) & np.in1d(x['Current_Status'],['Approved, paid'])).sum(),)))

def d(df):
    return df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(new_col1=(x['foo'] != np.nan).sum(),new_col2=(x['bar'] == 'P').sum(),new_col3=(x['bar'] == 'C').sum(),new_col4=((x['Status']=='Approved, not yet paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, paid')).sum(),new_col5=((x['Status']=='Approved, not yet paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, not yet paid')).sum(),new_col6=((x['Status']=='Approved, paid') & (x['Current_Status']=='Approved, paid')).sum())))
```

**Testing DataFrame**:

```
    id  foo bar                  Status          Current_Status
0    1   23   C          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
1    1   63   P  Approved, not yet paid          Approved, paid
2    1   84   P          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
3    1  125   P  Approved, not yet paid  Approved, not yet paid
4    1   12   C          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
5    2   23   C          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
6    2   63   P  Approved, not yet paid          Approved, paid
7    2   84   P          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
8    2  125   P  Approved, not yet paid  Approved, not yet paid
9    2  216   P  Approved, not yet paid          Approved, paid
10   2   12   C          Approved, paid          Approved, paid
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if it speeds it up.

Comment: I test it and it is 2 times faster.